# I am trying to simulate a non-inverting amplifier in Proteus. The result is fine with an AC signal, but when I apply DC the amplification is weird

Tags: operational-amplifier

Here is the schematic.  Next to it is the output. The amplification should be 2 but the simulation shows it to be 3. Is it because of offset?

[image]

Comment: You need to bias opamp so it operates in linear region.

Answer (score 0):

> but when I apply DC the amplification is weird

Here is the DC Analysis for your circuit, note that opamp is not a rail to rail input/output.

[image]

Here is "amplifier" ... note the DC offset.

[image]

Here is the characteristic of a rail-to-rail output.

[image]

Comment: Sorry Can you please explain what do you mean by rail to rail.....

Comment: A rail-to-rail ... means that voltage output (and inputs) can go from the negative power supply to the positive power supply. here, it means that output can go from 0 V to 5 V. So TL071 is not a rail-to-rail output ... TLC2272 is a rail-to-rail output.